# "Could not find a part of the path" file path error

Tags: c#, opentk

I'm following an OpenTK tutorial online and after following along, I'm still getting this error in the debug:

**Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Coding\OpenTK_HelloTriangle\OpenTK_HelloTriangle\bin\Debug\net6.0\Shaders\shader.vert'.**

Here's the code the error directs me to:

`var shaderSource = File.ReadAllText(vertPath);`

Here's where I reference the files I want the program to use (in a different project):

`_shader = new Shader("Shaders/shader.vert", "Shaders/shader.frag");`

Both the code projects mentioned above are outside the folder "Shaders", where the shader files are.

Comment: Well it seems you've specified the wrong path. Where are the files located that you want to use? If they are e.g. in `C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Coding\A\B` then you would have to specify either the absolut path like `C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Coding\A\B\shaders\shader.vert` or the relative path like `..\..\..\..\A\B\shaders\shader.vert`.

Comment: Specifying the absolute path worked for me, thanks.